# find and sed doesn't work in centos 7

Tags: linux, sed, find, centos7

I'm trying to find and replace a word in my entire project and I tried below versions of find and sed in centos 7 but nothing works.

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' s/mysql_/mysqli_/g \;
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' s/mysql_/mysqli_/g {} \;
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' 's/mysql_/mysqli_/g' {} \;
find ./ -name "*.php" -ls | xargs sed -i '' 's/mysql_/mysqli_/g'
```

> sed: can't read s/mysql_/mysqli_/g: No such file or directory

All above commands giving me this error in loop even though I'm running these commands from the root of my project. Permissions are all correct. If I simply use find command alone it's working

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -ls (This Works)
```

I tried solutions available in stackoverflow but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fist pair of quotes in `sed` aren't necessary, try:

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec sed -i s/mysql_/mysqli_/g {} \;
```

The syntax is either `-i'prefix'` or `--in-place='prefix'`, not `-i 'prefix'`, since you added an space between the prefix and the argument, it's making `sed` use the prefix (empty string) argument as the regex and use the actual regex as a filename argument, which obviously won't find.

That's why you are getting the `can't read s/mysql_/mysqli_/g: No such file or directory` error.

Comment: The -i parameter requires an empty string '' on OSX.

Comment: Then he should probably remove the space between `-i` and the prefix.